# I can't able to understand how while statement is working

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

```
class poll {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    List list = new LinkedList();
    list.add("Avi");
    list.add("ravi");
    list.add("savi");
    while (!list.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.print(list.poll() + " <-- ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: poll is used to delete the head element of the list.

Comment: Also, this won't compile because `List` doesn't declare a `poll` method. (Not to mention the use of raw types.)

Comment: What is your exact question, you don't know how while works generally in java or how it is working with poll here?

Answer (score 1):

`List` Does not have any `poll` method. It comes from `Queue` interface.Only  `LinkedList` implements both `List` and the `Queue` interface. You are creating an instance of `List` here instead of creating an instance of  `LinkedList`.

So better to use :

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList<>();
```